# How to change the div overflowing behaviour using flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two div elements which I want to center within an 'li' element. I found out that this could be done by using a flex layout. My parent div has the following properties:

```
display: -webkit-flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

This works and the two child divs are centering within the 'li'. Those are an image and a text element. But the additional behaviour this has, is not what I want. When the screen is too small for one line text, it is overriding the image. It looks like the following:

[image: Behaviour]

The more I shrink the page, the more the image dissappears. Does anybody know how this comes and how I can fix it?

**EDIT** Currently I am finding out how to add a working code snippet. For now, I have an image with the content structure, maybe this helps a bit.

[image]

I fill the image using the following css code:

```
.img_info_icon_png {
   background: url("adapter-images.png") no-repeat -432px -0px;
   width:  24px;
   height: 24px;
}
```

Although the width is set to '24px', it is changing within the browser.

**EDIT** The following url is pointing to an example with the same behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkpxhux0/

Comment: We need to see a _working_ code snippet reproducing the issue you encounter, so also add the HTML for the `ul`/`li`/`div` and its CSS

Comment: I will try to add one

Comment: And generally, there is no such issue with Flexbox https://jsfiddle.net/ehj17zak/ so you must have some other settings override it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `flex-shrink` defaults to `1`, it allows for the items to shrink when not fit its parent.

Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `.img_info_icon_png` rule.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.outer .image {
   background: url(http://placehold.it/50/f00) no-repeat;
   width:  24px;
   height: 24px;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    This is some text that should not overlap the left aligned image
  </div>
</div>
```